# Sort grouped nodes by taxonomy weight in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, sql-order-by, view, taxonomy

I have one vocabulary with 4 taxonomy terms

```
- Term A
- Term B
- Term C
- Term D
```

and there are some nodes which I grouped in views by taxonomy term, so the result looks

```
like this:
- Term 1
  - Node 1
  - Node 2
- Term B
  - Node 3
  - Node 4
... and so on...
```

Then I reordered terms, but there is no change when I look on the views page. Still the same order. So, please, what are the steps to make them ordered by weight?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll answer this question myself.. hope, that it helps some people..
In views just add `'Relationship' -> Content: Taxonomy terms on node` and then You can add in `'Sort criteria' -> (term) Taxonomy term: Weight (asc)`
That's all

Comment: What would cause the "'Sort criteria' -> (term) Taxonomy term: Weight (asc)" to NOT show up? I added the relationship, but the Sort Criteria for tax term weight is not even presented as an option.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer works just the same with Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

For me even after adding the "'Relationship' -> Content: Taxonomy terms on node"  the "'Sort criteria' -> (term) Taxonomy term: Weight " was still not available.

I found out that after checking "disable views data caching"  under admin/structure/views/settings/advanced  it became available (as well as a lot of other sort and filter criterias).
I noticed that checking "disable views data caching" was only necessary on remote host not on localhost.

I have no idea why this is so (I am not a drupal expert), but maybe it can help someone.